# interpolating categorical data in python? (nearest / previous value)

Tags: python, interpolation

How would one interpolate categorical (non-float, or in more broad sense, non-numerical) data in python?

#### Test data

Here is an example dataset with string-valued y-values.

```py
x = [1.4, 2.8, 3.1, 4.4, 5.2]
y = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B']
```

#### Expected outputs

```py
# with kind= 'nearest'
x_new = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_new = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B']

# with kind= 'previous', fill_value = None
x_new = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_new = [None, 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A']
```

I was expecting that [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) could do the job with `kind='nearest'` or `kind='previous'`, but unfortunately that is not the case.

Comment: Well, you can easily implement it yourself, can't you? Find the index of the nearest or previous value in x and then apply it to y. For me, this seems straight forward.

Comment: Sure. I was in the hope that there exists an off-the-shelf, speed optimized function for this. I can implement linear interpolation easily, too, and yet there are library functions for such tasks.

Comment: Related: Submitted a feature request for scipy interp1d: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/12222

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `interp1d` if you replace your target points with indicies. I.e. construct list of all unique values - in your case it will be `['A', 'B']`, transition `y` to be indicies instead of strings (indicies converted to float - you will be ok as long as number of unique elements can be stored as float without losing precision).

After interpolating you'll just need to get back elements given result of interpolation. As long as you use 'previous' or 'nearest' you'll always get floating point value which is one of your original indicies.

UPD.
Even simpler version would be to use `y_int = [float(i) for i in range(len(y))]`, as input for `interp1d`, then after you got your interpolation result just use it as index of `y`.

#### Example: `kind='nearest'`

```py
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np

x = [1.4, 2.8, 3.1, 4.4, 5.2]
y = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B']

f = interp1d(x, range(len(y)), kind='nearest', fill_value=(0, len(y)-1), bounds_error=False)
y_idx = f(x_new)
y_new = [y[int(i)] for i in y_idx ]
# ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B']
```

#### Example: `kind='previous'`

```py
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np

x = [1.4, 2.8, 3.1, 4.4, 5.2]
y = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B']
f = interp1d(x, range(len(y)), kind='previous', fill_value=-1, bounds_error=False)
y_idx = f(x_new)
y_new = [y[int(i)] if i != -1 else None for i in y_idx]
# [None, 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A']
```

Comment: Nice idea! I'll edit your answer to include the full code for implementation!